# XSLT dynamic javascript 'not' filtering

Tags: javascript, xslt

I had this school works asking to make an adressbook and filter is alphabetically. whenever I try to filter mine, I end up with my page reloading and showing all names and not filtering it at all. I've end up finding that whenever I call my apply() function the page reload and wont make any changes i just did. its not filter at all I'm at a loss about what is wrong ... anyone have any idea ? heres the main part of the xslt : I've try changing pretty much any value around to match the templates that was given to us in class but I cant make it work. ( the part I havent touch are the apply and init function (well aside from changing variable names )

Most of the related xslt search in here ends up focusing on XPATH and not the js part ...

```
 // <![CDATA[   

    function initFF(){
        xmlDoc = document.implementation.createDocument("","",null);
        xslDoc = document.implementation.createDocument("","",null);

        xmlDoc.load(" CarnetAdresse.xml");
        xslDoc.load("CarnetAdresse.xslt");

        xslDoc.addEventListener("load", initPointeurFF, false);
    }   

    function nameSpaceResolver(prefix){
        return "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform";
    }   
    function initPointeurFF(){

        noeudFiltre = xslDoc.evaluate("//xsl:apply-templates[@select='individu']/@select", 
                                                    xslDoc, 
                                                    nameSpaceResolver, 
                                                    XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
        objProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
        objProcessor.importStylesheet(xslDoc);

    } 

    function apply(){

            tempDoc = document.implementation.createDocument("","",null);

            frag = objProcessor.transformToFragment(xmlDoc.documentElement, tempDoc);

            document.getElementById("main").innerHTML="";
            document.getElementById("main").appendChild(frag);

    }


    function showByLetter(val){

      noeudFiltre.value = val;

      apply();
    }
```

now, whenever I call the apply function, no mather what I pass as XPATH value in my showByLetter function the page end up reloading and showing my all the adresses I have in my xml.

here are my templates if its needed ;

```
<body onload="initialiser()">
  <table>
     <tr>
     <td onclick="showByLetter('individu[nom = &quot;Test&quot;]')">test</td>>
     </tr>
  </table>
  <div id="main">
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="main-table">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="individu">
                <xsl:sort select="nom" order="ascending"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </table>
    </div>

<xsl:template match="individu">
<xsl:for-each select="./*">
        <tr>
        <td class="table-name"><xsl:value-of select="name(.)" /></td>
        <td class="table-content"><xsl:value-of select="." /></td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't the faintest idea what your apply() function is trying to do - either I'm missing something, or you have a very strange idea of what the processing model is.

You need to define a parameter to your stylesheet using xsl:param, and use the value of this parameter to filter the addresses. Then you need to set a value for this parameter from your Javascript using the transformation API.

Comment: sadly I'm not 100% sure either as I missed the day the prof show it ...

I dont know what is that transformation API, and that apply function works like a charm for the homework we had to do, I just dont know why i cant make it work here. technically it's suppose to empty the page ( the innerHTML ="")  than the appendchild is suppose to grab the parser buffer and show up the result ... but as I said I miss that class so I dont know the mechanics behind